# make an api request for each element on a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have this function:

```
updateCustomers = (input) => {

   //let urls = input;

   let urls = [{
    name: "localhost:8081",
    url: "http://localhost:8081"
},
{
    name: "localhost:8082",
    url: "http://localhost:8081"
},
{
    name: "localhost:8083",
    url: "http://localhost:8081"
}]

    const allRequests = urls.map(url => {

        let paramsNode = {
            customer: this.props.match.params.customer,
            environment: this.props.match.params.environment,
            action: 'check',
            node: url.name
        }

        sleep(2000).then(() => {
            this.gatewayService.manageServices(paramsNode).then((response) => {
                console.log("return " + response)
            })
        })

    })

    Promise.all(allRequests).then (function(results) {
        // API results in the results array here
        // processing can continue using the results of all three API requests
        console.log("HERE "+results)
    }, function(err) {
        // an error occurred, process the error here
    });
}
```

What I want to do here is to only ensure that the api calls are in order and to execute only one api call when the other is finished.
But when i run my code it doesnt do what I want.

Here is the prints that I get:

```
HERE ,,

RestUtils.js:13 fetchJsonFromApi {"exitCode":"0"}

RestUtils.js:13 fetchJsonFromApi {"exitCode":"0"}

RestUtils.js:13 fetchJsonFromApi {"exitCode":"0"}
```

The HERE print should present the return values from my api order but it is undefined `(HERE {"exitCode":"0"},{"exitCode":"0"},{"exitCode":"0"})`

Here is my API calls:

```
 manageServices=(params)=>{

    let url = this.baseUrl;

    if(params.customer == null || params.environment == null) {
        throw "The customer or environment parameter cant be null.";
    }

    url += "/" + params.customer + "/" + params.environment +  "/"+params.node  +"/configurations/manageServices/" + params.action;

    url = encodeURI(url);

    return RestUtils.fetchJsonFromApi(url);

}


static fetchJsonFromApi(url, callback) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log("fetchJsonFromApi " + JSON.stringify(json))
            // making callback optional
            if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(json);
            }
            return json;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

I just want to make sure that I make a call when the other is finished.

Update without the sleep function:

[image]

Comment: The callback function that you pass to `urls.map(...)` doesn't return anything which means that `allRequests` is an array of `undefined`.

Comment: Why do you need one api call to finish before next is made? They don't seem to be dependent on each other. Order of parallel requests results will be maintained if you use proper promise returns

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `return` statements in order to return promise chain to your map() array

```
   return sleep(2000).then(() => {
 // ^^^^  returns sleep() promise to map array
      return this.gatewayService.manageServices(paramsNode).then((response) => {       
      // ^^^^^  returns promise to the sleep `then()`          
            console.log("return " + response)
            return response;
          // ^^^^^ resolves the inner then() with response object and 
          // resolves the above promises and gets passed to Promise.all()
        });
      });
```

I suspect your sleep() was an attempt to fix ordering problem which was really caused by improper/missing `return`s. Removing it and keeping the other returns noted will work fine

Comment: if I remove the sleep my request will do all at the same time,updated to questoion with the picture @charlietfl

Comment: It will anyway ... all the sleeps will end at same time because the `map()` won't wait for them. Goes back to my question why you need to have them in serial rather than parallel?

Comment: so how do I do to force the requests to wait for the one before to finish?

Comment: do you really need to? They don't seem to be dependent on each other in the client side code

Answer (score 0):

use async/await to make your calls in a loop, blocking iteration until each call is finished:

```
const doCallsInOrder = async () => {
    const paramsNode_array = urls.map(url => ({
        customer: this.props.match.params.customer,
        environment: this.props.match.params.environment,
        action: 'check',
        node: url.name
    }))

    for (let i = 0; i < paramsNode_array.length; ++i) { // don't use a forEach
        const response = await this.gatewayService.manageServices(paramsNode_array[i])
        console.log("return " + response) 
    }
}
doCallsInOrder()
```

Comment: Why make an array with all the params beforehand, while you could simply construct each param object when you need it?

Comment: you're right, not really necessary. i was just trying to adhere to the OP's original code as much as possible. you'd just want to make sure to iterate over the `urls` array in a `for` loop rather than `Array.map` or `Array.forEach` as that would make complications for the async/await